# what query do I need to write to get the values in one of the rows of my table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to make a website with flask that allows students to register. On the registration page students are prompted to enter their 'chosen_class' which is then stored in a 'studentusers' table. So what I want to do is query the table and get the values in the 'chosen class' row.

At first I did a flask sqlalchemy query and got an empty list and then I tried to write an raw sql query and I got something else.

This was the empty list that I got when I did a sqlalchemy query:

```
p=StudentUsers.query.filter(StudentUsers.chosen_class).all()
>>> p
[]
```

And this is what I got when I did a raw SQL query:

```
>>> db.engine.execute('select (chosen_class)' 'from(StudentUsers)')
<sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy object at 0x0152F770>
>>>
```

This is an example of what's in the table:

```
StudentUsers('billy','jean','billy','year13', 'billyj@gmail.com','default.jpg')]
```

### what I want is these two classes to be printed out to me within the list rather than an empty list

### chosen_class

year12b
year13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this query:

```
SELECT chosen_class FROM studentusers;
```

you have to write following query in python:

```
chosen_classes = StudentUsers.query.with_entities(StudentUsers.chosen_class).all()
```

This query is going to return a list of tuples:
[('year12b',), ('year13',)] and you can then iterate through such list:

```
for class in chosen_classes:
     print(class[0])
```